# Why do my Component lost while rendering the next page?

Tags: reactjs, string, formula, display, mathjax

I'm using MathJax for the first time and I did success to display some simple formule like
'a x b = c' in a quizz whith several questions.

On the first page, my formula displayed well but not the others, as you can see on the inspector the component disappear...

Here is the first question :

[image: The first question]

And the second question :

[image: The second question]

Here is the code where I am mounting the component  :

```
function createRandomQuestions() {
        var nbQuestions = 10;
        var maxInt = 15;
        var randomQuestions = [];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < nbQuestions; i++) {
            var randomInt1 = getRandomInt(maxInt);
            var randomInt2 = getRandomInt(maxInt);
            var enounceModel = "\\({" + randomInt1 + "}\\times{"+ randomInt2 + "} = \\)";
            console.log(enounceModel)

            var question = {
                enounce: <MathJaxDisplay 
                            enounceModel={enounceModel}/>
                           ,
                answer: randomInt1*randomInt2
            }
            randomQuestions.push(question);
        }
        CustomLogger("randomQuestions", randomQuestions, 'TableTestHome')
        setQuestions(randomQuestions);

        return randomQuestions;
    }
```

And

> MathJaxDisplay

is just a custom Component englobing the regex :
`"\\({a}\\times{b} = \\)"`;

```
import React from 'react';
import { MathJax, MathJaxContext } from "better-react-mathjax";

const MathJaxDisplay = ({enounceModel}) => {

    return (
        
        <MathJaxContext>
            <MathJax>
                {enounceModel}
            </MathJax>
        </MathJaxContext>
    );
}

export default MathJaxDisplay;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to add the `dynamic` flag to the `MathJax` component

Comment: Also, can you show the code where you switch questions? Best would be a sandbox with the problem but you could start by just showing how the questions are switched.

Comment: The flag dynamic solves the problem

Comment: Ok, I guess then that you're somehow updating the `MathJax` component as opposed to creating a new one, then it will only be typeset the first time, but by adding the `dynamic` flag, you tell it that it might be further updated. Can't tell for sure without seeing the code where the questions are shown but if it solves your problem and you're happy with that, then fine :)

Comment: Yes, but something new happens after adding the dynamic flag.
In the first occurrence, it is wrongly displayed (like the problem solved) but for a fraction of seconds.

Comment: Yes, it's because MathJax hasn't finished typesetting, you can try `hideUntilTypeset={ "every" }` to hide the content until it's typeset. Let me know if it works well for you

Comment: It did ^^

Thank you